# Removing options from Select dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

I have a "From" dropdown and a "To" dropdown. Both the elements have the same set of options.

I'm trying to take off elements of the 2nd dropdown depending on whatever is selected in the first dropdown. This way I want to eliminate the possibility of ever having the same option in both the "from" and the "to" field. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#from").change(function() {
    var str = $("#from option:selected").val();
    $("#to option[value=str]").remove();
    console.log(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>From</label>
<select id="from">
  <option value="Onety One">11</option>
  <option value="Twenty Two">22</option>
  <option value="Thirty Three">33</option>
</select>
<label>To</label>
<select id="to">
  <option value="Onety One">11</option>
  <option value="Twenty Two">22</option>
  <option value="Thirty Three">33</option>
</select>
```

This does not seem to be working. Can someone please help me out and let me know what could possibly be wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the **str** variable. And you need quotes inside `[value='']`
 
Change this line:

```
$("#to option[value=str]").remove();
```

to this :

```
$("#to option[value='"+str+"']").remove();
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're code on the option selection is a bit twisted, try this

$("#to option:selected").remove();

instead of

$("#to option[value=str]").remove();